# Issues with Multiple IF Formulas in one cell in Google Sheets returning a Formula Parse Error

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I'm creating a small risk calculator in Google Sheets. You select two word-based values from a drop down menu and that should spit out the risk "score" in a third column that consists of adding two numerical values together. It looks like this:

[redacted image]

I thought using this should work to get the first number.

```
=IF(C7="Frequently"; 4; 0), IF(C7="Likely"; 3; 0), IF(C7="Occasionally"; 2; 0), IF(C7="Seldom"; 1; 0)
```

It works to get the first number, but when I put the second IF in, it starts to give me an error. Is it because it can't put both a four and a zero in at once? So it's not able to return a value? If that's the issue, how do I fix this?

I assumed it'd differentiate between the logical_expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of the `IF` function is:

```cpp
IF(condition; value_if_true; value_if_false)
```

So the correct way to write that formula is:

```cpp
=IF(C7="Frequently";4;
   IF(C7="Likely";3;
     IF(C7="Occasionally";2;
       IF(C7="Seldom";1;0))))
```

However, I recommend using the [`SWITCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013690) function as it's more concise and it doesn't require the repetition of the cell reference (`C7`):

```cpp
=SWITCH(C7;"Frequently";4;"Likely";3;"Occasionally";2;"Seldom";1;0)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and I was successfully able to make this calculator work! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=ifs(C7="Frequently",4,
     C7="Likely",3,
     C7="Occasionally",2,
     C7="Seldom",1,
     1,0)
```

- *Just in case your sheet uses [semi-colon based convention](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sheets-location/), replace all the commas `,` in the above formula with semi-colon `;`*